# How to combine multiple planning entities for solving one problem in OptaPlanner?

Tags: java, optaplanner

Given:

```java
Employee {
    int id;
    int minJobNum;
    int maxJobNum;
    int totalWorkTime;

    @OneToMany
    List<Job> jobs;

    @ManyToOne
    Vehicle vehicle;
}

@PlanningEntity
Job {
    @PlanningId
    int id;

    @ManyToOne
    Employee employee;

    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "employeeRange")
    private Employee employee;
}

@PlanningEntity
Vehicle {
    @PlanningId
    int id;
    int capacity;

    @OneToMany
    @PlanningListVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "employeeRange")
    List<Employee> employees;
}
```

cost matrix:

```java
List<Cost> costs;

Cost {

    Job from;
    Job to;
    Long time;

}
```

Here is the main class:

```java
SolverFactory<Solution> solverFactory = SolverFactory.create(new SolverConfig()
        .withSolutionClass(Solution.class)
        .withEntityClasses(Job.class, Vehicle.class)
        .withConstraintProviderClass(SolutionConstraintProvider.class)
        .withTerminationSpentLimit(Duration.ofSeconds(5)));

Solution problem = generateDemoData();

Solver<Solution> solver = solverFactory.buildSolver();
Solution solution = solver.solve(problem);

ScoreManager<Solution, HardMediumSoftScore> scoreManager = ScoreManager.create(solverFactory);
ScoreExplanation<Solution, HardMediumSoftScore> scoreExplanation = scoreManager.explainScore(solution);
System.out.println(scoreExplanation.getSummary());
System.out.println("Is Feasible: " + scoreExplanation.getScore().isFeasible());
```

My Constraints:

```java
public class SolutionConstraintProvider implements ConstraintProvider {

    @Override
    public Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return new Constraint[]{
                minJobNumberConflict(constraintFactory),
                maxJobNumberConflict(constraintFactory),
                vehicleCapacity(constraintFactory),
                vehicleMaxCapacity(constraintFactory)
        };
    }

    private Constraint minJobNumberConflict(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(Job.class).groupBy(Job::getEmployee, count())
                .filter((employee, count) -> 10 > count)
                .penalize("minJobNumberConflict",
                        HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_MEDIUM, (employee, count) -> 10 - count);
    }

    private Constraint maxJobNumberConflict(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(Job.class).groupBy(Job::getEmployee, count())
                .filter((employee, count) -> count > 30)
                .penalize("maxJobNumberConflict",
                        HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_HARD, (employee, count) -> count - 30);
    }

    private Constraint vehicleMaxCapacity(ConstraintFactory factory) {
        return factory.forEach(Vehicle.class)
                .filter(vehicle -> vehicle.getEmployeeList().size() > vehicle.getCapacity())
                .penalizeLong("vehicleMaxCapacity",
                        HardMediumSoftLongScore.ONE_HARD, vehicle -> vehicle.getEmployeeList().size() - vehicle.getCapacity());
    }

    private Constraint vehicleCapacity(ConstraintFactory factory) {
        return factory.forEach(Vehicle.class)
                .filter(vehicle -> !vehicle.getEmployeeList().isEmpty())
                .filter(vehicle -> vehicle.getEmployeeList().size() < vehicle.getCapacity())
                .penalizeLong("vehicleCapacityConflict",
                        HardMediumSoftLongScore.ONE_SOFT, vehicle -> vehicle.getCapacity() - vehicle.getEmployeeList().size());
    }

}
```

My Solution class:

```java
@PlanningSolution
public class Solution {

    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "employeeRange")
    private List<Employee> employees;

    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    private List<Vehicle> vehicles;

    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    private List<Job> jobs;

    @PlanningScore
    private HardMediumSoftScore score;

    public Plan(List<Employee> employees, List<Job> applications, List<Vehicle> vehicles) {
        this.employees = employees;
        this.jobs = jobs;
        this.vehicles = vehicles;
    }

}
```

- Each employee has a min and max jobs number. For example, each employee must do more than 10 jobs and less equals 30 jobs.
- Each vehicle has capacity. Еhe number of employees should not exceed the number of vehicle capacity
- Each job has an address and a coordinate.
- Separately, for each pair of work (addresses) there is a time to reach the point (cost matrix).
- The total time (taking into account the time to reach the route and 20 minutes to complete each job) should not exceed the employees totalWorkTime;

When i try to run the code i get the following error:

> The entityClass (class Vehicle) has a @PlanningVariable annotated property (employeeList) that refers to a @ValueRangeProvider annotated member (field private java.util.List Solution.employees) that returns a Collection with elements of type (class Employee) which cannot be assigned to the @PlanningVariable's type (interface java.util.List).

Comment: This is not a good question. What have you tried so far? What issues did you run into? Read https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/planner-configuration/planner-configuration.html#modelAPlanningProblem to learn about planning domain modeling. Think about what you want OptaPlanner to change during solving (that will be your planning variable, there can be more than one). What I don't understand about your problem definition is how do you want to use a vehicle to transport multiple workers, each working on a different job?

Comment: I can solve the problem of placing employees in transport, as well as the problem of distributing work among employees individually. But it is not possible to combine them into one code so that it is calculated together. I will update my question shortly and add the solutions I added. thanks a lot

Comment: I have updated the question and added more information to clarify the issue.I hope you can suggest a solution to this problem. Thank you in advance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good use cases with multiple planning entity classes are rare. They require custom moves, which makes them labor intensive. We are working on improving the easy of use of that though.

However, in most cases, it's better to do multi-stage planning instead, **business wise**. [I think I discussed that in this video.](https://youtu.be/Ew6pq9nJKog) Conway's law etc.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for the help. I used multi-stage planning for solving optimization problem.